# Creating a 6x4 grid in qml

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I am trying to create a grid, consisting of squares. It is a 6X4 grid. The code which I  am using to make the grid is below

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Mini Keno")
    ColumnLayout {
        spacing: 1
        Item {
            Row {
                spacing: 1
                Repeater {
                    id: mmm
                    model: 5
                    Rectangle {
                        id: imgl
                        width: 50
                        height: 50
                        color: "#4286f4"
                        property string src: ""
                        MouseArea {
                            anchors.fill: parent
                            onClicked: {
                                parent.color = "4286f4"
                                parent.color = "#2345F6"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Item {
            Row {
                spacing: 1
                Repeater {
                    id: mm2
                    model: 5
                    Rectangle {
                        id: img2
                        width: 50
                        height: 50
                        color: "#4286f4"
                        property string src: ""
                        MouseArea {
                            anchors.fill: parent
                            onClicked: {
                                parent.color = "4286f4"
                                parent.color = "#2345F6"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code is I am trying to create two lines of the grid, but the other line is not visible. So how to solve this problem of the grid where the squares are clickable. Also, how can I place the grid in the middle of the window?

Comment: You can remove each parent of the `Row`s (the two `Item`s).
And add `anchors.centerIn: parent` as a property of the `ColumnLayout`.

Comment: Whe don't you use a [`Grid`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-grid.html)

Comment: Or [GridLayout](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-gridlayout.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`height` and `width` properties missing for `Item`, so Item has zero height, width. So the second row is overlapped with the first row.

Use anchors to make the layout in center, i.e `anchors.centerIn: parent`

---

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Mini Keno")
    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.centerIn: parent  // place layout in center
        spacing: 1
        height: 100
        Item {
            width: 300  // widht of item
            height: 50  // height of item
            Row {
                spacing: 1
                Repeater {
                    id: mmm
                    model: 5
                    Rectangle {
                        id: imgl
                        width: 50
                        height: 50
                        color: "#4286f4"
                        property string src: ""
                        MouseArea {
                            anchors.fill: parent
                            onClicked: {
                                parent.color = "4286f4"
                                parent.color = "#2345F6"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }                
            }            
        }
        Item {
            width: 300  // widht of item
            height: 50  // height of item
            Row {
                spacing: 1
                Repeater {
                    id: mm2
                    model: 5
                    Rectangle {
                        id: img2
                        width: 50
                        height: 50
                        color: "#4286f4"
                        property string src: ""
                        MouseArea {
                            anchors.fill: parent
                            onClicked: {
                                parent.color = "4286f4"
                                parent.color = "#2345F6"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

---

[image]